# function pointer C programming

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm not sure what the following does and i'm hoping someone can clarify the purpose of having the asterisk in front of the functions name:

```
char *Foo(char *ptr) {

return NULL;
}
```

I understand that you can pass by value the memory location of something in the function argument call and *ptr would be the pointer to it. I understand you can create a pointer function that can be used to point to other functions like a regular pointer points to variable memory location but in this case this is not a function pointer that we can point to other functions, or is it? This seems like a real function.

Comment: No. Please go back one step and read a good beginners' C tutorial. And use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org).

Comment: Ask yourself what the asterisk does in front of that parameter. That should tell you something.

Comment: What about if you read as `char* Foo(char* ptr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its misleading you, the * by the name isn't related to the name

it means the same as `char* Foo(char* ptr)`

which means a function which takes a `char*` and returns a `char*`

Comment: Nevertheless, it's better to stick the star to the identifier following it, since not doing so is even more misleading: `char* a, b` isn't intuitive (the `*` qualifies the object, not the type).

Answer (score 2):

Foo is a function.

It has input: `ptr` of type `char*`

It has output of type `char*`

`char*` means "pointer to `char`"

it returns NULL.

That is the most plain explanation I can think of.

Comment: "input" and "output" are called an "argument" and the "return value".